# Mapping .jsp Spring

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets

Today I'm working on a project in Java Spring, especially in `CONTEXT-SERVLET.xml` (context) where normally declare a bean to link a `.jsp` with a Java class or controller (mapping).

Traditional workflow is: a `viewA.jsp` is linked (mapping) to `controller.java` (controller) and this `controller.java` dispatches another `viewB.jsp`.

Can you link a `viewA.jsp` to another `viewB.Jsp` without going through a controller?
How do this in `CONTEXT-SERVLET.xml`?

Comment: In Java classes are named like `MyNiceClass`. `controller` is not a valid class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ParameterizableViewController`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ParameterizableViewController.html) to redirect a request to jsp file without visiting controller.
For example
1. Mapping `/welcome.htm` to `welcomeController`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/welcome.htm">welcomeController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

2. Mapping `viewName` property of `welcomeController` to `WelcomePage`

```
<bean name="welcomeController" 
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController">
        <property name="viewName" value="WelcomePage" />
</bean>
```

3. Defining view resolver

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
            <property name="prefix">
              <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
              <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
 </bean>
```

It will map `/welcome.htm` to `/WEB-INF/pages/welcomePage.jsp`.
[Source](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-parameterizableviewcontroller-example/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

< mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home" />

This is a shortcut for defining a ParameterizableViewController that immediately forwards to a view when invoked. Use it in static cases when there is no Java controller logic to execute before the view generates the response.

see link http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-view-controller